# D3.js show heatmap for each pixel (coordinate) in choropleth

Tags: d3.js, choropleth

In D3.js choropleth map, we assign a color to each state or city. is there any solution or example that we can assign heatmap to each coordinate (my data are values from satellites so i have a value for each coordinate).In matlab or matplotlib I plot a figure and then apply borders but it seems it's not possible in D3. i want something like this [image: fig]
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

folium python package have geojson (choropleth) mapping function that we can define rectangles (polygons, for example zip code regions). for more information [interactive choropleth map](https://vverde.github.io/blob/interactivechoropleth.html)
and [popuo on map](https://www.jpytr.com/post/analysinggeographicdatawithfolium/). my result

[image: my result]